# Calculate direction and speed of movement from azimuth and range from a point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I wasn't sure where exactly to put this on stackexchange, so hopefully this is the most appropriate place.

Problem: I am working with Level3 Data from the NEXRAD Radar network. Specifically, the NSS/62 "Storm Attributes Table" product. This table gives you a lot of characteristics regarding various attributes of doppler-indicated storms.

One of the things it gives you, is "AZRAN (DEG/NM)". A sample table looks like this:

```
STORM      AZRAN      BASE     TOP    CELL BASED VIL    MAX REF    HEIGHT     
  ID      DEG/NM       KFT     KFT       KG/M**2          DBZ        KFT

 T7       51/ 21      9.4     9.7           0             35        9.4
 M3      152/ 31      3.6     4.9           0             34        4.9
```

I believe the AZRAN is the Azimuth, and Range, relative to the radar site, expressed in degrees and nautical miles respectively.

What I would like to do, is using the AZRAN for a particular storm cell from current table, the same from the previous table, and the time difference between when they were created, to calculated an approximate speed and cardinal movement direction of a given storm cell.

I've never tried anything quite like this, and have no idea what to even search for, much less where to start.

Edit: Better way to ask: "Given two points at different times, a1 and a2, each containing the azimuth and distance from a second stationary point b, and the time, how do you calculate the speed and direction of a?"

Comment: This may not be the best place. Seems to be far more to this than just mathematics.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I wasn't sure. I wish there was a weather related stackexchange. :(

Answer (score 0):

Without been given a diagram, I am guessing you have the following:

at t1: location P1 at range A1, azimuth a1

at t2: location P2 at range A2, azimuth a2

You can use the cosine rule in the triangle oP1P2 to find the distance D as the length of the vector from P1 to P2 as $$D^2 = (A1)^2 + (A2)^2 - 2(A1)(A2)\cos(a1-a2).$$

You then find the internal angle d between A1 and D from the sine rule as $D/\sin(a1-a2)=A2/\sin(d)$. [The remaining angle between D and A2 in the triangle is then $b=\pi-d-(a1-a2)$.] The speed then follows as D/(t2-t1).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/3JYT9 <-- the numbers here are bogus of course, but it illustrates the concept of what I'm trying to do. That is what two scans would look like, all I have is the azimuth relative to the radar, the distance from the radar, and the time difference.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to word the question should have been: "Given two points at different times, a1 and a2, each containing the azimuth and distance from a second stationary point b, and the time, how do you calculate the speed and direction of a?"